Why does Python time out when importing a file?
I'm attempting to use motor driver software on the Jetson Nano. I have been successful previously with this  tutorial, but now when I ssh into the Jetson Nano, navigate to the jetson/jetson directory, launch a python 3.8 instance, and run import robot (all steps that worked perfectly well a month ago) I instead get:
>>> import robot
The qwiic drivers are not installed - please check your installation


I never receive an opportunity to input another line of code (the >>> prompt never appears). NOTE: I got the "qwiic drivers not installed" error like the one above last time I used this code - back then, it did not appear to affect functionality. The only new error is the timeout.
I have tried installing qwiic drivers but the terminal tells me the requirements are "already satisfied", so I'm not sure what's going wrong here.
